# When search between two dates if date not exists then returned true value

Tags: php, mysql

This is my booking table

[[image: Booking Table[1]]

I want values if I will search between two dates like column book_form = "2016-12-30" and book_to = "2017-01-05" it will be return false because the date 2017-01-05 exists in the booking table between two dates of this column book_from "2017-01-01" and book_to "2017-01-11".

this is my query and it return always empty value.

```
select * FROM room_book where room_book.book_from >= '2016-12-30' AND room_book.book_to <= '2017-01-03'
```

Comment: check `num_rows` if > 0 return `false` else return `true`.

Comment: You are using AND in where clause, so one situation is okay but 2nd fails so it is returning empty. If you are strictly filter for these days then it will return empty.

Answer (score 0):

Check your end date its 11, and you are querying till 3rd so it will return empty only.

Use this

```
select * FROM room_book where room_book.book_from >= '2016-12-30' AND room_book.book_to <= '2017-01-11'
```

Comment: select * FROM room_book where room_book.book_from >= '2016-12-30' AND room_book.book_to <= '2016-12-30'

Comment: if i search by this query then it will be return true value..i want your query in the negative value